# Setting System & HW time in Linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to change the current time in Linux with the following c++ code:

```
time_t * t = new time_t(QString::toLongLong(argv[1]));
int returnValue = stime(t);
qDebug() << (QString("set time return value %1").arg(returnValue));
qDebug() << (QString("setting time %1").arg(*t));
QProcess pProcess;
pProcess.start("hwclock", QStringList() << "-w " << "-u");
```

And even if the return value returns no error (it is 0), the time that I give with argv[1], is not set. To verify it, after the program execution, I type "date" to the terminal and it is not set. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: hwclock sets the motherboard RTC, not the system time.  The RTC is only used to initialize system time at boot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not passing time to `hwclock`. Where "--set"? where is the "--date" or its analog?

Second, proper utility to set system date and time is `date`.

Comment: I am setting the time with stime and according to documentation, the argument '-w': "Set  the  Hardware  Clock  from  the  System  Clock,  and  update the timestamps in /etc/adjtime.  " http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man8/hwclock.8.html

Comment: @epi4  O_o That ain't change  nothing from `date` POV. That sets hardware clock to the current system clock. `date` reads system clock.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the OS (Ubuntu 16.06) was resetting time. I had to execute the following commands in terminal:

```
systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
```